# Spring Security permitAll() for one URL under some pattern

Tags: spring, spring-security, basic-authentication

I have /my-app/login url and I want to permitAll() for this URL. But this page under /my-app/** pattern which permit access only for registered user.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/my-app/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
    }
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Add `.antMatchers("/my-app/login").permitAll()` BEFORE `.antMatchers("/my-app/**")...` . The request matchers are stored in an list (ordered by the order in which they are defined), and Spring security will use the first rule thats matchers match to the current request. So put the most specific first and the common rules afterwards.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/my-app/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/my-app/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
}
```

*If `my-app` is the name of your application, and therefore the url that is by your application server (Tomcat) to map the url to the application, then you have to ommit it in the `antMatcher` because the `antMatcher` is configured "only" by the application relative url: `/my-app/login` become `/login` and `/my-app/**` become `/**`*

<strike>add `.anyRequest().permitAll()` as last "matcher" of `authorizeRequests()`</strike>

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http

            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/my-app/**").access("hasRole('USER')")
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(entryPoint());
}
```

*But to be honest: you use some kind of black listing (allow all URLs except some black listed) - and this is not the recommended way (from some security perspective). Because if you forget to add or misspell one URL that should been protected, then it is accessible for every body. The more secure way is to deny every url and allow only some (white list).*

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice to just add .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/my-app/login").permitAll()"  for  login and adding denyAll() in the end?

Comment: @amant: you are right, I have understood the question in a wrong way. So I have changed the answer.